# Cannot import ephem

Tags: python, pyephem

I'm having a problem importing ephem under windows.  I think it is a 32/64 bit problem.

```
Z:\>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ephem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ephem\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ephem._libastro as _libastro
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>>>
```

I would rather not have 32 and 64 bit python on the same machine if I can avoid it.

Thanks,
KR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try pyephem-3.7.5.1.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyephem.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks so much.  And so quickly!